# Entity Framework Many To Many Relations: Search if contains all

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I've been on this problem for a while and I have no ideia how to do it. I have this Model:

```
public class ConversationDB
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public virtual List<UserDB> Participants { get; set; }
}
```

and this

```
public class UserDB
{    
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public String Username { get; set; }
        public String FirstName { get; set; }
        public String LastName { get; set; }
        public String Email { get; set; }
        public String Password { get; set; }

        public virtual List<ConversationDB> Conversations { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm currently struggling on is searching for a conversation that has all elements of a list of participants say:

```
ConversationDB conversation = db.Conversations.Where(c => c.Participants.OrderBy(p => p.Username).SequenceEqual(partList.OrderBy(p => p.Username))).FirstOrDefault();
```

This code altough it gives me an error. What is the correct procedure I should take?

EDIT: I came with this ugly and stupid solution, but is basically what I want:

```
IEnumerable<ConversationDB> convs = db.Conversations.AsEnumerable();
foreach(UserDB u in partList)
{
      convs = convs.Where(c => c.Participants.Contains(u));
}
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information:  LINQ to Entities doesn't recognize the method 'Boolean SequenceEqual[UserDB](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microphoton.Models.UserDB], System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microphoton.Models.UserDB])', thus this method cannot be converted into an expression.

Comment: Sequence equal is a linq to object function

Comment: What do you mean @johnny5? I'm a newbie onmm EF, could you give me a good tutorial about everything I need to know? I get the feeling that I only understand the very basic of EF.

Comment: @RicardoAlves the methods you can use inside `Where` are limited to ones that EF can understand and translate. `SequenceEqual` is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Why not :)

```
ConversationDB conversation = db.Conversations.Where(c => c.Participants.Count() == db.Users.Count());
```

I think, you can't add one user twice.

Or, more formal way:

```
ConversationDB conversation = db.Conversations.Where(c => db.Users.All(u => c.Participants.Contains(u)));
```